# Running SSRS report against Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure, reporting-services

We're converting our SSRS reports to run against Azure SQL DB. They were previously run against on-prem SQL DB. We ran into an issue where we simply cannot run the reports from Visual Studio. We're getting an very generic error (An error occurred during local report processing). When I simply run a query in a Dataset query window, it returns the data with no issues. It's when I preview the report in visual studio, I get this error. Is anything extra needed to configure this Azure SQL DB?

Thanks.

Comment: Running the query will only test the dataset query and the associated datasource. Do you have any other data sources or datasets that could be invalid? I would suspect old datasource connections. Does the output window give any more details.?

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield There's only 1 datasource and 1 dataset in this report. I purposely created a very simple report just to test this.Output window doesn't have anything else besides this generic message. I have couple of date parameters so as soon as I enter them and press Run button, I get this message.

Comment: Maybe permissions issue or Azure firewall

Comment: Hi @PatrickGoode I doubt it since the account under which the report is running can actually run queries from datesets and I don't believe it would've let me set up a datasource if I didn't give right credentials and the account wasn't able to connect to this DB.

Comment: Maybe the dates are being converted incorrectly, maybe azure has a different format than your in house server. Try hard coding the dates in the dataset query and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield Tried that approach (hard-coding the dates right into the query) and got the same result. Actually, I uploaded the rdl file to the reporting server and ran it from there and it worked just fine. I think the issue is with the infrastructure and how I connect versus how the reporting server connects to this DB.

Comment: @Tony do you mean the problem is solved now?

Comment: Hi @LeonYue I solved it by using shared datasource instead of a local one. I defined the shared datasource exactly the same as my local one which wasn't working, so I have no idea why it works with a shared datasource but doesn't want to work with a local one.

Comment: Good morning @Tony, we may can't explain why it does't  work with the local one , but still congratulations  that you have solved it after all. I help you post it as answer. You may think about mark it as answer, this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations Tony has solved the problem by himself:

"I solved it by using shared datasource instead of a local one."

I help him post it as answer, this can be beneficial to other community members.